# How to increase the console font size and to enable color output in Yocto Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, console, yocto, bitbake

I would like to increase the font size and to enable color output for the Linux console during early boot. It is currently printed out using the graphics card (i.e., i915 connected to HDMI monitor) and the font is hard to read and there are many `[0;1;Xm[` printed which I believe is a change in color.

I am building my system using Yocto and was unable to find any information in the mega manual about this. I was able to find [this bitbake recipe (console-tools 0.3.2)](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/console-tools/console-tools_0.3.2.bb?h=zeus) which seems to be relevant to what I want to achieve but I don't know whether I also need to change something in the kernel configuration or perhaps somehow configure the graphics driver.

Any suggestions would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel comes with [fonts built into it](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/36h2km/linux_kernel_builtin_console_fonts/). You will need to check the `defconfig` you are using in the bitbake recipe to figure out which are built into yours. Assuming you already have one in there that is bigger (higher AxB values), you should just need to pass that value to the boot arguments the kernel takes when it is launched by the boot-loader. You do this via the `fbcon` [parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt):

> 1. fbcon=font:
>
>    ```
>     Select the initial font to use. The value 'name' can be any of the
>     compiled-in fonts: 10x18, 6x10, 7x14, Acorn8x8, MINI4x6,
>     PEARL8x8, ProFont6x11, SUN12x22, SUN8x16, TER16x32, VGA8x16, VGA8x8.
>    ```
>
>    Note, not all drivers can handle font with widths not divisible by 8,
>    such as vga16fb.